# stuck in running android application in AVD

Tags: java, android, mobile

So I downloaded the ADT bundle at the android website. I tried making a simple project, the one with HelloWord program. I already added an AVD and tried to run my application. At first, I got stuck at

"Waiting for HOME ('android :process:acore') to be launched"

but after searching the net, I learned that I must right click my project and click run as Android Application and then it was able to proceed with the next lnes in the console.

But after some lines, it gets stuck at the line in the console saying

"Starting activity.com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity on device emulator:5554"

it's been an hour since that line and nothing has happened in the AVD. I tried using 2 ADT bundles, one for my 32-bit computer and one for my 64-bit computer. Both get stuck at the same line. How do I solve this? I've been working with this issue the whole day. Just when I thought it would be a simple installation.

Comment: What's your IDE? Is the emulator running, when you start the app? What does the emulator's log say?

Comment: When I click eclipse, it opens an IDE called ADT I think. My emulator by the way can't get past the screen where it says ANDROID. It can't go to the home screen. What do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Launch your emulator from Android Virtual Device(AVD) Manager and run your application

Comment: I already did that. It seems my emulator is not working properly since it can't even go to the home screen. It is stuck in the screen where it only shows android.

Comment: The first time, the emulator starts up, that screen is there for a **really** long time. That's normal. Just take the time and wait for it to go away. It may take several minutes.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can really stick your program is a virtual device that is eating up too many resources. Try lowering the amount of RAM your virtual device has. Also be sure you have the latest JDK/JRE installed.
Just picked this book up:
[http://www.amazon.com/Android-Development-From-Eclipse-ebook/dp/B00EEI5NHO/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EEI5NHO)
Decently well written an very easy to follow. Walks through building an app in decent detail.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the AVD works very slow on normal configuration systems, it requires a very high config PC to run smooth, you have to wait for sometime to continue with AVD, it will start don't worry. But I would recommend you to run and test your apps on a real android device using the USB debugging feature.